# Chain rule misunderstanding : two different use of it give two different answers...

Tags: tensors, chain-rule, general-relativity, index-notation

I am studying G.R an I have a mistake by using chain rules (yes probably very basic mistake) that I don't get.

Take the following quantity (there is Einstein convention here, the $X$ and $V$ are vectors and $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$ are two different system of coordinates.):

$$ X^{\beta} V^{\sigma} (\frac{\partial y^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial y^{\mu}}\frac{\partial^2 y^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\alpha} \partial x^{\sigma}})$$

I need to "simplify" it.

I can  do it in two different ways.

First, I can use the summation over $\mu$ :

$$ \frac{\partial y^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial y^{\mu}}=\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}}=\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta} $$

I also could use the summation over $\alpha$ (other "method" to simplify it):

$$\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial y^{\mu}}\frac{\partial^2 y^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\alpha}x^{\sigma}}=\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial y^{\mu}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial y^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\sigma}}=\frac{\partial y^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\mu} \partial x^{\sigma}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\sigma}}\frac{\partial y^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\mu}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\sigma}}\delta^{\rho}_{\mu}=0$$

Thus, if I use the first thing I will end up with :

$$ X^{\beta} V^{\sigma} (\frac{\partial y^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial y^{\mu}}\frac{\partial^2 y^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\alpha} \partial x^{\sigma}})=X^{\beta} V^{\sigma} (\frac{\partial^2 y^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\beta} \partial x^{\sigma}}) \neq 0$$

And if I use the second method I end up with :

$$ X^{\beta} V^{\sigma} (\frac{\partial y^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\beta}}\frac{\partial x^{\alpha}}{\partial y^{\mu}}\frac{\partial^2 y^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\alpha} \partial x^{\sigma}})=0$$

It is probably a very stupid mistake or a more deep incomprehension thing but I really don't see it.

Could you help me figure this out ?

Comment: Whenever I get into a system where mystical notation gets in the way of intuition, I back up and try a simple example.  So my advice is to set $n=2$  and try two different coordinate systems on the same patch (for instance, the sphere, or projective space).

Comment: Generally, $$\biggl[ \frac{\partial}{\partial y^{\mu}}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\sigma}} \biggr] \neq 0.$$ In other words, we typically have $$\frac{\partial^2 y^{\rho}}{\partial y^{\mu} \partial x^{\sigma}} \neq \frac{\partial^2 y^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\sigma} \partial y^{\mu}}.$$

Comment: Combining the points from Matthew Leingang's and Daniel Fisher's comments above: you can't change the order of derivatives like this even in the case $n=1$. For example, take $y=x^2$ (on the region where $x>0$), then $\frac{d}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dy} 2x = \frac{d}{dy}2\sqrt{y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} = \frac{1}{x}$, while $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dy} = \frac{d}{dx} 1 = 0$.

Comment: @Litho
Oh ok thanks. In fact to make a link with the Schwartz theorem, in this theorem we assume we have independant variables whereas in my case it doesn't work as $y(x)$ (the schwartz theorem works if I vary a variable independantly from the others which is impossible here). So yeah at the end I can't commute. Thanks

Comment: (But of course for the same reason I can commute how I want the $\partial_{x_i}$ between them and the $\partial_{y_j}$ between them also)

Comment: Maybe [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2532711/are-these-mixed-partial-derivatives-equal) useful. We can show explicitly why the mixed partial derivatives not equal.